# Google Tag Manager - preview/debug tracking working vs. regular site doesnt track

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I want to set up clicks tracking for button on website, implement tracking for Google Analytics and Facebook Pixel. Everything works well when testing site in Preview/Debug mode of GTM. GA and FB tracks events as planned. I Submitted version in Google Tag Manager and Published it.

Problem is following: Website tracking in normal mode doesnt work, for example website in Incognite mode is not tracked. Where in the Submit/Publish process in GTM could I have made a mistake?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Incognito mode will sometimes block 3rd party tracking so it wouldn't show. I recommend using Google Tag Assistant add-on to test the tracking.

Comment: I tried also other browser with w/o incognito mode, no success..

Comment: There could be a number of reasons... Do you modify datalayer on the website in any way? Sometimes that can overwrite GTM. I'd suggest trying Tag Assistant to see what is causing the issue, if there are any problems with the code.